# Notice: Undefined index: notOne

Tags: indexing, undefined

Getting the following error:

Grabbing No1 
 **Notice**: Undefined index: notOne in **/home/public_html/Grabber/grabber.php** on line **221**

Here is the grabber.php file
http://pastebin.com/HUdYur0D

I was able to fetch the content from few sites, but getting the above error for other sites.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting the `notOne` index of the variable `$rusWords` and when you're trying to access it you get that error.

Comment: can you please set it for me as i have shared the file already...i am newbie with php..still learning it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `notOne` element in the `$rusWords` array.

```
if($ok == 0) exit($rusWords['notOne']);
```

should probably be:

```
if($ok == 0) exit($rusWords['notAnyOneLoaded']);
```

Comment: I am getting some weird characters like this
�� ������ ����� �� ���������. �������� �������� � ����������� ��������

Actually it should import some data from the defined website. But showing the above characters. What do you think the problem might be?